# Msg 3151: the database that was dumped was not quiescent when the dump was performed

Tags: sap-ase

I am working on loading database dumps to a new ASE server, but when I try to load 15gb and 32gb dumps to a database, I get the below error:

> Msg 3151, Level 16, State 2: Server 'TestServer', Line 1:
>
> Adaptive Server cannot load this database because the database that was dumped
> was not quiescent when the dump was performed. Run sp_flushstats
> before DUMP DATABASE and ensure that the database is not updated
> during the dump.

When I load a 2gb dump to a db, everything is fine. I searched on the net and they advise to get db dump with `sp_flushstats` in single user more but I have no chance to get new dumps.

```
load database db1
from       'compress::/home/aykut/db1_1'
stripe on  'compress::/home/aykut/db1_2'
go
```

These dumps were taken from an ASE 12.5 instance located on a Solaris Sparc and I'm trying to load these dumps in to an ASE 12.5 instance located on Linux x86. Is that causing an issue? Or can this error be related to ASE Developer Edition's database size limit?

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  Is your Sybase Developer or Express?  Developer should not have any file size limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read official docs about crossplatform dump.

PS: You must redumped database. Before dump you must run DB in singlemod and call sp_flushstats. After database loaded - dbcc reindex, update statistics, sp_recompile.

http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1033627

Comment: It also helps to dump the transaction log before running sp_flushstats